# VBA Automatically Saving incoming emails from outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to write a small macro program for outlook.
The Program Should automatically save the text of incoming emails as a text file.

I found large pieces of code and tried to make this work but it still won't work.

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum olSaveAsTypeEnum
    olSaveAsTxt = 0
    olSaveAsRTF = 1
    olSaveAsMsg = 3
End Enum

Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items


Private Const MAIL_PATH As String = "C:\mails\"
'Private Const MAIL_PATH As String = "C:\Users\dirk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\"


Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

Private Sub ItemsItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    SaveMailAsFile Item, olSaveAsTxt, MAIL_PATH
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveMailAsFile(oMail As Outlook.MailItem, eType As olSaveAsTypeEnum, sPath As String)
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sExt As String

    Select Case eType
        Case olSaveAsTxt = sExt = ".txt"
        Case olSaveAsMsg = sExt = ".msg"
        Case olSaveAsRTF = sExt = ".rtf"
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
    sName = oMail.Subject
    RecplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

    dtDate = oMail.RecievedTime
    sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & sExt

    oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, eType


End Sub

Private Sub RecplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, sChr As String)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ";", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "Chr(34)", sChr)

End Sub
```

I wrote this code not in a separate module but in the already existing `ThisOutlookSession` module.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message do you have? What is not working? Also, about `ItemAdd` event (not sure you are using it properly): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220152%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: (1) This code needs to go in a class module. (2) You need to instantiate the class when Outlook starts.

Answer (score 0):

Also, about ItemAdd event (not sure you are using it properly): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220152(v=office.12).aspx –  dnLL

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    SaveMailAsFile Item, olSaveAsTxt, MAIL_PATH
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.